# WebApp using Ionic 3 or latest

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic so it may possible that my question is of baby level but then too I want to know presence of any browser platform in ionic 3. I know the ionic application runs on browser but as i have to add platform for android if I have to run it on android device.

So is there any presence of web platform which specifically build application for web?

If I would like to make web application using Ionic so can I?

Comment: Ionic is a CLI that allows compilation of native JavaScript application to native mobile application. You generally integrate ionic to an angular or react project, if you wish to deliver a webapp AND mobile application

Comment: So what is the requirement to design its own UI markups?

Comment: You can create custom styles using the ionic cli,  the cli is just a compiler that takes JavaScript as input and outputs a mobile app.

Comment: So can we say if we don't compile it specifically for any device still the existing code can be treated as web application?

Comment: Yes, if not using ionic cordova, the generated application is a webapp. See: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/

Comment: Thanks Maxime got it.

Comment: one more question Maxime, If I use Bootstrap or Angular material instead of ionic UI tags so how would it affect when I build app for android and ios

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164239/discussion-between-lalit-kushwah-and-maxime-flament).

Comment: It seems to me that some components from material have a dependency to the browser, like their dialogs, and don't allow the compilation of the project to mobile applications. Check other posts on StackOverflow, I read this in some posts